# Wordpress permalink is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks

Once I create a new page in wordpress, I change the permalink settings from 'Default' to 'Post name'. Now I trying to visit my page, but the page is lost. Im getting this error -

```
Not Found

The requested URL /anonymous/sample-page/ was not found on this server.
```

Plz help, thnkz.

Comment: Watch this video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxka7P2hV0c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you working as Localhost and want to set permalinks then be sure to activate the rewrite_module in the  "httpd.conf" file  that locate in "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf" or "C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\conf\original"

find the line  "#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" and remove the "#" its mean enabling the functionality and save the file and restart your server then you enable permalink it would work

Answer (score 0):

Set the Permalink again to Default and then to Postname, and check it again.

It worked for me ;)

Comment: Do you clear the Wordpress Cache after? With W3 Total Cache or another Plugin?

Comment: No, How to do that? I'm a beginner.

Comment: Download it, configure it and then you can easly clean your Cache: [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Delete the .htaccess file and create new .htaccess file. And Update the permalink. And check htaccess file is the code is updated.
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following in your .htaccess file's IfModule mod_rewrite.c tag

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

It worked for me..